# How to get my virtual machine (VirtualBox) accessible on a company network?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, arch-linux

I created an Arch Linux VM guest using VirtualBox on my Windows desktop at work. I'm planning to use it for Django development because there are no Unix machines available to use as a workstation at work.

From the VM guest I can ping/SSH to other machines in the network, but not the other way around. It's like even though the guest machine has an IP address on the network and a hostname, neither is recognizable.

Comment: This is probably more a superuser question.  What is your network adapter set to?  HostOnly, NAT, Bridged?  just reread after I posted.  Was thinking vmware, so this might not apply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your VM to be accessible on the network you need:

- Change the Network mode from NAT to bridge
- If no DHCP server is present, statically assign an available IP address that belongs to your network
- Check for security in guest machine (this is not related to VirtualBox but to networking)